# React Hooks state nao atualiza

Tags: react, react-hooks

Estou enfrentando um problema com a atualização de um State usando react hooks. O problema consiste em que, posteriormente
a aplicação de um `.filter()` tento aplicar o valor resultante da filtragem realizada em um setProducts() e quando eu faço um console.log() para verificar o products do setProducts ele está vazio.
OBS: Quando eu coloco o debugger para visualizar oque esta acontecendo, percebo que o setProducts recebe o valor normalmente…[imagem exemplo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN9wb.png)/[imagem exemplo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKIjF.png)

```
const [original, setOriginal] = useState([]); //recebe os valores da API sem nenhum filtro
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]); //aqui deve receber os valores após o filtro
  const [apply, setApply] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadProducts() {
      const response = await api.get("/product");
      setOriginal(response.data.product);
    }
    loadProducts();
  }, []);

  const handleChange = event => {
    const { value, name } = event.target;

    var filtered = original.filter(
      el => el[name] === value || el[name] === parseInt(value)
    );
    setApply(true);
    setProducts(filtered);
    console.log("orginal", original);
    console.log("filtrado", filtered);
    console.log("products", products);
    debugger;
  };
```

Comment: Eu sou leigo em React, posso estar escrevendo maior besteira, mas coloque o código de setProducts() pois o array original tem itens, filteredtem um item então o filtro funcionou me levando a crer que setProducts() foi quem falhou.

Answer (score 1):

O problema, neste caso, é que a função `filter` retorna um novo array (de acordo com a condição), então, cada vez, que `el => el[name] === value || el[name] === parseInt(value)` é verdadeiro, o array `filtered` retorna o um novo array somente com os valores que passaram pela condição. É por isso que `products` (no console), no final, está vazio. Abraços.
Referência:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro#Descri%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 0):

Veja se assim funciona:

```js
setProducts([filtered]);
```